# induction to prove $n^2 - 1$ is divisible by 4 by changing variables

Tags: number-theory, induction

I have to prove $n^2 - 1$ is divisible by $4$, where $n\in\mathbb{O}_{>0}$.

It says, "You cannot prove this by induction on $n$. Rewrite $n^2 - 1$ in terms of a variable on which you can do induction."

Why is it not possible to do this by induction on $n$ and how would I change the variable?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $\Bbb{O}$ supposed to be the set of odd integers? This is very nonstandard notation.

Comment: "You cannot prove this by induction on n." The person (?) having commited this nonsense should be hanged.

Comment: More importantly, the person demanding this be done by induction should be subjected to judgmental looks.

Comment: Yes $\mathbb{O}$ is supposed to be the odd set. Hanged? My prof got her phd from Columbia so I would hope she must know better.

Comment: {1,3,5,...,2k+1,2k+3,...} I don't see why induction couldn't be apply to the odd numbers. But whatever I guess they want you to change n to 2k+1 and only look at the set {1,2,3,4...,k,k+1,...}

Comment: It is much easier to just use a direct proof but we happened to be working on induction at the moment and I suppose she was looking for an easy exercise to make a point

Comment: Most likely, "you cannot" means "you are not allowed to".

Comment: I think his prof is saying that we cannot induct on $n$. We may replace $n$ by $2k+1$ and induct on $k$ instead

Comment: I agree with Barak: that "you can't" most probably meant "you're not allowed to".  +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text you are using takes a pretty narrow view of what it means to prove by induction. The statement is: $1^2-1$ is divisible by $4$, and if $k^2-1$ is divisible by $4$ where $k$ is odd, so is the next odd number ($k+2$). But
\begin{equation*}
  (k+2)^2-1 = k^2+4k+4-1 = (k^2-1) + 4(k+1),
\end{equation*}
which is divisible by $4$ since $k^2-1$ is by the inductive hypothesis.

I assume that what the text means is that since we are assuming $n$ is odd, we should instead use the statement $(2k+1)^2-1$ is divisible by $4$ if $k$ is a nonnegative integer. That is proven in much the same way: true for $k=0$, and if true for $k$, then
\begin{equation*}
  (2(k+1)+1)^2-1 = 4k^2 + 12k+9-1 = 4k^2+4k+4 + 8k+5 = (2k+1)^2 - 1 + 4(1+2k).
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

If $f(n)=n^2-1$

$f(m+2)-f(m)=(m+2)^2-m^2=4(m+1)$

$\iff4\mid f(m+2)\iff4\mid f(m)$

Now $f(1)=?$

Comment: In fact, $(2a+1)^2=8\dfrac{a(a+1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod8$

Answer (score 1):

Put $\;n=2k-1\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , so

$$n^2-1=(2k-1)^2-1=4k^2-4k+1-1=4k(k-1)$$

and clearly the rightmost term is divisible by $\;4\;$ so we're done.